# cache coherence overhead compared with linux signal / conditional variable

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, caching, signals

I have a question about cache coherence overhead. I want to design a very fast responsive communication tunnel. This is in memory communicate with two thread/process in different cpu. It's one on one or broadcast communication which means it has only one writer but might have one or more reader. They use share memory. The tunnel might be a round buffer with an integer as its writing position in the head. Assume writer and each reader are in different CPU and all are realtime system with no context switch.

One way can be, each reader maintains their own reading position and they spin and loop to check their position with writer position in the buffer. Once they found that the two integers are different, that means readReady and reader can read one element and move their reading position ahead one element. This is read modify write condition but since it's very atomic basic type (like integer or bytes), only one write, and assume memory alignment is also regular, this should be safe and fast. The only problem is when the writer writes the value into the cache(assume intel cache is write back), the modification does not spread to other cache immediately, and reader reads their own cache and thinks the value is not changed. Hardware will do cache coherence automatically so soon reader can get the modification but this brings some overhead.

I know the most traditional way to implement this is using signal or conditional variable to make the reader wait for writer's notification. I am worried about those method might have system call and brings hundreds of cycles overhead, or make thread sleep waitup and brings even larger lag. I'm not expert on this problem. I want to know which way is better if the only thing we concern is latency? Or is there any better way? Thanks

Comment: `I want to know which way is better if the only thing we concern is latency?` - Even from the view of latency choose is very dependent: from target machine, from its workload, from the buffer's usage scenario (how many contentions, how long wait), and so on. The most effective way for choose is **measure** required values on *actual workload* and compare them.

Comment: The measure is time. That means from the time the writer modify the value until the reader knows the value is modified. Assume they are in two cpu (different core of one cpu) in one machine with a shared memory. The cpu is quite clean and in realtime sched (FIFO), the reader continues spin to check the value is modified, no other workload.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong, nevermind. Actually, from the view of latency *busy-waiting* is always better choice. As for cache coherence latency, you may use `cache drop` instruction before reading value. But I am unsure that it will give your more benefit than simple reading in loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is ONLY latency, then busy-waiting will give you much lower latency. Unfortunately, it will also give you much higher power-consumption and higher CPU usage.

For some applications, the high CPU usage is not an issue, but if the user has a lap-top or mobile phone type device, it's a REALLY bad solution, as it will eat the battery (and in case of some devices, slow things down because you have managed to heat up the CPU enough that the thermal management kicks in to reduce the speed of the device). Even on servers that are plugged in, power consumption can not be ignored - the heat generated by the CPUs in a server room has to be extracted via air-conditioning - as to running costs, the AC is often the same cost as the cost of running the server itself. So if you write an excellent app that is better than everyone else's, but uses more power through busy waiting, then it's likely to put you in disadvantage compared to competing products in the same market.

It is also bad for the performance of other applications in the system. Again, not a problem if you have a dedicated system with enough cores to cope with your app and whatever else it needs to. It would be a problem if it's running in a general purpose machine.

Of course, it also depends on whether you expect the one thread to be constantly sending out messages, or if it's sitting idle every now and again.

The actual length of a simple system-call is in the order of 100-1000s of cycles (depending what OS version, what processor, etc), and if the OS decides to run something else, it may well end up being a much larger number.